# Where do I find event logs for computers being added to or disconnected/deleted from the domain?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domain, domain-controller, windows-event-log

Since I activated Directory Services logging I wanted to find the logs concerning computers being added with the domain and being deleted/disconnected from the domain.

I've been looking through our "Directory Service" logs and was not able to find any logs that show information about this.

The "find" function also wasn't able to find any logs when looking for the recently added computer name.

Is there any smarter way to find these logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll list the Event IDs you're concerned with:

- Event ID 4741 - A computer account was created.
- Event ID 4743 - A computer account was deleted.

In order to see these Event IDs in Event Viewer (either logged in directly to your Domain Controller or remotely) you'll need to create a Group Policy Object **for your Domain Controller(s)**:

```
Computer Configuration
   -Policies
      -Security Settings
         -Advanced Audit Policy Configuration 
            -Audit Policies
               -Account Management
```

Enable *Audit Computer Account Management* with at least *Success*. I have *Success* and *Failure* enabled to track both.

Also, here is a nice TechNet Step-by-Step guide on Advanced Audit Policy.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd408940(v=ws.10).aspx

[image]